# Firebird Update append

Tags: sql, firebird

So what I need is to append a string in a column on a firebird database everytime I run the update, I'm trying:

```
update clients set cliobs = coalesce(cliobs, '') || 'newstring' where cod = 1
```

I get the 1 record(s) was(were) updated but the end result is:

```
coalesce(cliobs, ') || newstring
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  If your field = 'foo' and your new string was 'bar', that update statement should update it to 'foobar' .

Comment: somehow it is giving me 'coalesce(cliobs, '') || bar' in the database... maybe I'm doing something else wrong...

Comment: Sounds like you are quoting the entire value, is this the actual query/code?